# Component not updating as often as it should be on React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state, rendering

I am working on a project based on NextJS. What I am trying to accomplish is a file upload with progress bar. The upload works just fine, but the render of my component just updates once or twice in all the progress.
This is the method I use for uploading the file (with axios):

```
    static async uploadFileToCenter(centerId:string, file:any, progressCallback) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(`uploaded_file`, file);
        return api.post(`/centers/${centerId}/uploadFiles`, formData, {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => { progressCallback(progressEvent, file) },
        });
    }
```

This is the code I use for the actual component rendering:

```
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    const progressCallback = (progressEvent, file) => {
        const fileIndex = files.findIndex(f => f.name === file.name);
        const progress: number = Math.ceil((progressEvent.loaded as number * 100) / progressEvent.total);
        console.log(progress);
        files[fileIndex].progress = progress;
        setFiles(files);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!files || files.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        setUploading(true);
        files.forEach((file) => {
            CenterService.uploadFileToCenter(center._id, file, progressCallback).then(response => {
                const uploadedFile = response && response?.data?.data?.url;
                const tempFiles = (center?.files) ? [...center.files, uploadedFile] : uploadedFile;
                if (tempFiles) {
                    formik.setFieldValue('files', uniq(tempFiles));
                }
                setUploading(false);
            });
        });
    }, [files]);

    function Thumbs() {
        return <div className="uploaded-files-container"> 
            {files.map(file => (
                <div className="uploaded-file-container" key={file.name}>
                    <div className="thumbnail-container">
                        <div className="thumbnail" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${file.preview || '/_next/static/media/bg-searchTreatment.aa8648dea68731269b666fbe58cd505f.jpg'})`}}></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="details-container">
                        <div className="progress-indicator" style={{width: `${file.progress}%`}}></div>
                        { file.progress && <div className="progress-number">{ file.progress }%</div> }
                        <div className="file-name">
                            {file.name}
                        </div>
                        <div className="file-size">
                            {(file.size/1024).toFixed(0)}KB
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="actions-container">
                        { file.progress && file.progress < 100 && <Spinner /> }
                        { !uploading && <a onClick={() => removeImage(file)}><Image src="/assets/remove.svg" height="30" width="30" /></a> }
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    };
```

As you can see here, I get to see all the progress on the console, but not reflected on my Thumbs component:
[image]

Maybe I am missing something obvious, since I am fairly new to React.

Comment: Is files set somewhere else than `setFiles(files);`? I don't see the place where you add the file, that line doesn't do anything, as it passes files to itself, did you mean to update their progress along these lines? I see that you change the state without setFiles before, but still it is not adding an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your progress callback:

```js
files[fileIndex].progress = progress;
setFiles(files);
```

It could be due to the fact that you are updating `files` with the same reference as before, you might have to do a copy before calling `setFiles`

```js
const newFiles = [...files]
newFiles[filesIndex].progress = progress;
setFiles(newFiles)
```